# Logical Constraints in SCIP PySCIPOpt

Tags: scip

Please explain how logical constraints work in PySCIPOpt. I tried reading about `model.addConsOr` and `model.addConsAnd` but could not understand. An example would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to add logical constraints to a model using PySCIPOpt:
https://scipopt.github.io/PySCIPOpt/docs/html/tutorial_2logical_8py_source.html

example code:

```
x = model.addVar("x", "B")
y = model.addVar("y", "B")
z = model.addVar("z", "B")
r = model.addVar("r", "B")
model.addConsAnd([x,y,z], r)
```